# How to convert decimal value to string type

Tags: asp.net, decimal, currency

I'm trying to show the Total amount into word

Following is the code i'm using :-

```
public void amountinwords()
{
string word = ConvertNumbertoWords(Convert.ToInt32(popopop.Text));
amountttiinwwords.Text = word;
}

public static string ConvertNumbertoWords(int number)
{
if (number == 0)
return "ZERO";
if (number < 0)
return "minus " + ConvertNumbertoWords(Math.Abs(number));
string words = "";

if ((number / 1000000000) > 0)
{
words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 1000000000) + " Billion ";
number %= 1000000000;
}

if ((number / 10000000) > 0)
{
words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 10000000) + " Crore ";
number %= 10000000;
}

if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
{
words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 1000000) + " MILLION ";
number %= 1000000;
}
if ((number / 1000) > 0)
{
words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 1000) + " THOUSAND ";
number %= 1000;
}
if ((number / 100) > 0)
{
words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 100) + " HUNDRED ";
number %= 100;
}
if (number > 0)
{
if (words != "")
words += "AND ";
var unitsMap = new[] { "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "TWELVE", "THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN", "EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN" };
var tensMap = new[] { "ZERO", "TEN", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FORTY", "FIFTY", "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY" };

if (number < 20)
words += unitsMap[number];
else
{
words += tensMap[number / 10];
if ((number % 10) > 0)
words += " " + unitsMap[number % 10];
}
}
return words;
}
```

but it is fetching error System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
because the value is in decimal form (example - 8452.3)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JPnC.png)

Can anybody help me with this

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You are converting it to Int32 not Decimal or Double. Now there is `Convert.ToDouble()` `Convert.ToDecimal()` But i would suggest the [decimal.TryParse(string,out decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) to make possible to return error if the provided string is not parsable.

Comment: Sir can you explain it with this code ???

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` method expects a string which can be converted to an integer. If you pass a decimal number string to this method it is gonna throw the `FormatException`. Also, your `ConvertNumberToWords` method will not work with a decimal number as you are expecting an integer in its parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you say :

```
string word = ConvertNumbertoWords(Convert.ToInt32(popopop.Text));
```

your saying that a string type is equal to an integer. The left side does not equal the right. Text is also not a string.  When you want to convert something to an int and you want it to be a string. You use the ToString method.

```
here is an ex i just tested:

         double c = 100; 
//-------original double val
                    string d = Text.Plain;
///----im on console so I made it a text class
                    d = c.ToString("F3");
// cast to string and F3 is numbers after decimal you want
```

//----------------------------------------------------///
IT works for me:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
     string amountttiinwwords = Text.Html;
            string popopop = Text.Html;
            popopop = "-2"; // the input from yoo

            string word = ConvertNumbertoWords(Convert.ToInt32(popopop));
            amountttiinwwords = word.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(amountttiinwwords);

}


 private static string ConvertNumbertoWords(int number)
        {
            if (number == 0)
                return "ZERO";
            if (number < 0)
                return "minus " + ConvertNumbertoWords(Math.Abs(number));
            string words = "";

            if ((number / 1000000000) > 0)
            {
                words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 1000000000) + " Billion ";
                number %= 1000000000;
            }

            if ((number / 10000000) > 0)
            {
                words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 10000000) + " Crore ";
                number %= 10000000;
            }

            if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
            {
                words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 1000000) + " MILLION ";
                number %= 1000000;
            }
            if ((number / 1000) > 0)
            {
                words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 1000) + " THOUSAND ";
                number %= 1000;
            }
            if ((number / 100) > 0)
            {
                words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 100) + " HUNDRED ";
                number %= 100;
            }
            if (number > 0)
            {
                if (words != "")
                    words += "AND ";
                var unitsMap = new[] { "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "TWELVE", "THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN", "EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN" };
                var tensMap = new[] { "ZERO", "TEN", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FORTY", "FIFTY", "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY" };

                if (number < 20)
                    words += unitsMap[number];
                else
                {
                    words += tensMap[number / 10];
                    if ((number % 10) > 0)
                        words += " " + unitsMap[number % 10];
                }
            }
            return words;

        }
```

Comment: Not working Againg fetching same error    Input string was not in a correct format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help...
i found my solution .... i'm using this code and it is working for me !!!!

```
 public String changeToWords(String numb)
    {
        String val = "", wholeNo = numb, points = "", andStr = "", pointStr = "";
        String endStr = ("");
        try
        {
            int decimalPlace = numb.IndexOf(".");
            if (decimalPlace > 0)
            {
                wholeNo = numb.Substring(0, decimalPlace);
                points = numb.Substring(decimalPlace + 1);
                if (Convert.ToInt32(points) > 0)
                {
                    andStr = ("point");// just to separate whole numbers from points/Rupees

                }
            }
            val = String.Format("{0} {1}{2} {3}", translateWholeNumber(wholeNo).Trim(), andStr, pointStr, endStr);
        }
        catch
        {
            ;
        }
        return val;
    }

    private String translateWholeNumber(String number)
    {
        string word = "";
        try
        {
            bool beginsZero = false;//tests for 0XX
            bool isDone = false;//test if already translated
            double dblAmt = (Convert.ToDouble(number));
            //if ((dblAmt > 0) && number.StartsWith("0"))

            if (dblAmt > 0)
            {//test for zero or digit zero in a nuemric
                beginsZero = number.StartsWith("0");
                int numDigits = number.Length;
                int pos = 0;//store digit grouping
                String place = "";//digit grouping name:hundres,thousand,etc...
                switch (numDigits)
                {
                    case 1://ones' range
                        word = ones(number);
                        isDone = true;
                        break;
                    case 2://tens' range
                        word = tens(number);
                        isDone = true;
                        break;
                    case 3://hundreds' range
                        pos = (numDigits % 3) + 1;
                        place = " Hundred ";
                        break;
                    case 4://thousands' range
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                        pos = (numDigits % 4) + 1;
                        place = " Thousand ";
                        break;
                    case 7://millions' range
                    case 8:
                    case 9:
                        pos = (numDigits % 7) + 1;
                        place = " Million ";
                        break;
                    case 10://Billions's range
                        pos = (numDigits % 10) + 1;
                        place = " Billion ";
                        break;
                    //add extra case options for anything above Billion...
                    default:
                        isDone = true;
                        break;
                }
                if (!isDone)
                {//if transalation is not done, continue...(Recursion comes in now!!)
                    word = translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(0, pos)) + place + translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(pos));
                    //check for trailing zeros
                    if (beginsZero) word = " and " + word.Trim();
                }
                //ignore digit grouping names
                if (word.Trim().Equals(place.Trim())) word = "";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ;
        }
        return word.Trim();
    }

    private String tens(String digit)
    {
        int digt = Convert.ToInt32(digit);
        String name = null;
        switch (digt)
        {
            case 10:
                name = "Ten";
                break;
            case 11:
                name = "Eleven";
                break;
            case 12:
                name = "Twelve";
                break;
            case 13:
                name = "Thirteen";
                break;
            case 14:
                name = "Fourteen";
                break;
            case 15:
                name = "Fifteen";
                break;
            case 16:
                name = "Sixteen";
                break;
            case 17:
                name = "Seventeen";
                break;
            case 18:
                name = "Eighteen";
                break;
            case 19:
                name = "Nineteen";
                break;
            case 20:
                name = "Twenty";
                break;
            case 30:
                name = "Thirty";
                break;
            case 40:
                name = "Fourty";
                break;
            case 50:
                name = "Fifty";
                break;
            case 60:
                name = "Sixty";
                break;
            case 70:
                name = "Seventy";
                break;
            case 80:
                name = "Eighty";
                break;
            case 90:
                name = "Ninety";
                break;
            default:
                if (digt > 0)
                {
                    name = tens(digit.Substring(0, 1) + "0") + " " + ones(digit.Substring(1));
                }
                break;
        }
        return name;
    }

    private String ones(String digit)
    {
        int digt = Convert.ToInt32(digit);
        String name = "";
        switch (digt)
        {
            case 1:
                name = "One";
                break;
            case 2:
                name = "Two";
                break;
            case 3:
                name = "Three";
                break;
            case 4:
                name = "Four";
                break;
            case 5:
                name = "Five";
                break;
            case 6:
                name = "Six";
                break;
            case 7:
                name = "Seven";
                break;
            case 8:
                name = "Eight";
                break;
            case 9:
                name = "Nine";
                break;
        }
        return name;
    }


 public void amountinwords()
    {
        string value = total.Text;
        string a = value.ToString();
        string[] b = a.Split('.');
        int firstValue = int.Parse(b[0]);
        int secondValue = int.Parse(b[1]);

        amountttiinwwords.Text = changeToWords(firstValue.ToString());
        taxamountinwords.Text = changeToWords(tax.Text);   
    }
```

Thanks ....